# How to CREATE a password protected zip file in iOS

Tags: ios, encryption, ios7, passwords, zip

I'v gone through multiple libraries like [SSZipArchive](https://github.com/soffes/ssziparchive) and [ZipArchive](https://code.google.com/p/ziparchive/) for creating password protected zip files . But both these libraries does not have the option to create a password protected zip file. They only have the option to unzip a password protected file.

Are there any libraries/ API's that allows us to CREATE a zip file with password protection.

Comment: A for Alpha, what did you end up doing? Thanks.

Comment: Can you please tell me how to unzip a password protected file with ZipArchive

Answer (score 2):

As I see this is not closed yet, I´m using SSZipArchive and it does already have the ability to create password protected zips:

```
 func createZipFileAtPath(path: String!, withFilesAtPaths paths: [AnyObject]!, withPassword password: String!) -> Bool
```

Answer (score 1):

Check out https://github.com/flyingdolphinstudio/Objective-Zip/tree/master/Objective-Zip

They do password protection.

Comment: this library seems to have an option to ONLY OPEN an password protected file but i could not find a way to zip a file with password. Did i miss something here?

Comment: I think it can create and open password protected zips.

Answer (score 1):

I have recently used ZipArchive (https://code.google.com/p/ziparchive/downloads/list) in a project. Although I did not use password protection, it does have that facility.

Comment: This library creates a zip folder with a password and then adds individual files to the protected folder. Its working fine till this case, but it is not allowing me add folders into the protected folder? Any thoughts on this?  Basically, i am looking to zip a folder with nested folders.

Comment: Unfortunately I created the zip file with files only (no sub folders).